# Change display arrangement in OS X/macOS programmatically

Tags: display, applescript, command-line

I periodically have to move my display around (physically<sup>[1](http://#footnote-1)</sup>) and this requires also rearranging my display arrangement in System Preferences.  Manually doing this all the time is a pain in the neck.  Is there any way to do it programmatically?

---

<sup>1</sup> I work on one side of a table when I'm working solo, but when I want to pair with someone I flip to the other side of the table because it has more unused space available for a second person.  Flipping the display around to face the other side of the table means the display goes from being to the right of my laptop to being to the left, since the laptop goes on a stand either way.

Comment: Just a note... I modified the code as there was no need to replicate what I previously did in the `if normalOrentation ...` _statement_. That just needed to cover info for the _toggle flag_. The replicated _code_ has been moved out and set below it.

Answer (score 33):

Sorry for the late answer. You can use displayplacer to set profiles for both of your arrangements. Save the profiles in a script or use something like BetterTouchTool for a hotkey to change your monitor layout.

https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer

Comment: There is no reason to apologize for answering after a long period of time.  Neither I nor anyone else has a right to _expect_ your answer.  Your answer is just as useful to anyone who is searching for a solution to this problem.  I appreciate your work—and your answer—and plan to make it a part of my setup.  Thanks!

Comment: Can confirm.  I'm looking in 2021.

Answer (score 17):

I figured out how to automate the display switching using a keyboard shortcut with `displayplacer` and it works like a charm!

I setup a macro using [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) to automatically cycle the desktop arrangement using a keyboard shortcut.

**Instructions to setup Keyboard Shortcut**

1. Install [displayplacer](https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer) using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh)
2. Use Keyboard Maestro and create a Macro
3. Add the Execute Shell Script Action for each display you have (I have 3).
4. Open System Preferences > Displays and change your arrangement by placing the menu bar to the right by 1 screen (right-to-left type direction)
5. Open your terminal and run the `displayplacer list` command
6. Copy the bottom output, e.g. `displayplacer "id:<screenId> res:<width>x<height> hz:<num> color_depth:<num> scaling:<on/off> origin:(<x>,<y>) degree:<0/90/180/270>"`
7. Paste the output into your Macro Action.
8. Repeat steps 4-7 and stop after you've done the main screen you keep your menu bar on.
9. Setup a keyboard shortcut for your Macro.
10. Run your Macro with your new shortcut and watch the magic happen right before your eyes.

**Helpful Tips**

1. If you have an issue with running `displayplacer` from Keyboard Maestro, it's likely that you're using a different bash in your terminal/iTerm like oh-my-zsh when you installed it using Homebrew. If thats the case, follow these instructions from [my other post](https://superuser.com/a/1517733/1129659) to fix your `displayplacer` binary reference.
2. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvxv3.jpg) to view my working Keyboard Maestro setup with `displayplacer`.
3. You may need to run your macro a second time if you accidentally hit your shortcut.

Comment: Awesome! It works like a charm. Does your KM macro swap them automatically? How can I make that when I trigger the macro it just swaps them?

Comment: I am using BetterTouchTool and I set it up to show a context menu when Mission Control button is pressed with two options (left and bottom) for my side car iPad configuration. Works like a charm! Be sure to use full path to the displayplacer when providing command to BetterTouchTool terminal action (/opt/homebrew/bin/displayplacer in my case).

Answer (score 10):

Using my MacBook Pro, which normally sits to the left of my Thunderbolt Display, and my Thunderbolt Display, the following will show how to use [hsscreens](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/hmscreens/hmscreens.html) and AppleScript to toggle the two arrangements programmatically based on how it's currently arranged. The end result is an AppleScript application that when run simply toggles back and forth between the two arrangements. This app can be run in all the normal ways any other application can be run.

In the image below, you see the *normal* and *flipped* arrangements of the Displays and Menu bar showing the difference relationships between my MacBook Pro and Thunderbolt Display.

[image: Screen Arrangements]

This AppleScript application, along with the `hsscreens` binary executable file, programmatically toggles between the two arrangements shown in the image above, shifting  the MacBook Pro's Display to the right or left of the Thunderbolt Display maintaining the Menu bar on the MacBook Pro's Display.

To *code* this, I needed to determine what the *current arrangement* was and then act accordingly. To do this I used `hmscreens -info` in a Terminal twice, once while in each *arrangement*.

Looking at the outputted information I saw a piece of info that I could `grep` for, in order to the set a *flag* to toggle against.

---

Output of `hmscreens -info` in a *normal arrangement* of the Displays:

```
$ hmscreens -info
Screen ID: 68822100
Size: {1440, 900}
Global Position: {{0, 0}, {1440, 900}}
Color Space: NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace
BitsPerPixel: 32
Resolution(dpi): {144, 144}
Refresh Rate: 0
Uses Quartz Extreme: YES

Screen ID: 68695180
Size: {2560, 1440}
Global Position: {{1440, -540}, {4000, 900}}
Color Space: NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace
BitsPerPixel: 32
Resolution(dpi): {72, 72}
Refresh Rate: 0
Uses Quartz Extreme: YES

$
```

---

Output of `hmscreens -info` in a *flipped arrangement* of the Displays:

```
$ hmscreens -info
Screen ID: 68822100
Size: {1440, 900}
Global Position: {{0, 0}, {1440, 900}}
Color Space: NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace
BitsPerPixel: 32
Resolution(dpi): {144, 144}
Refresh Rate: 0
Uses Quartz Extreme: YES

Screen ID: 68695180
Size: {2560, 1440}
Global Position: {{-2560, -540}, {0, 900}}
Color Space: NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace
BitsPerPixel: 32
Resolution(dpi): {72, 72}
Refresh Rate: 0
Uses Quartz Extreme: YES

$
```

---

If was obvious, to me, I needed to use info from `Global Position:` to determine what the *current arrangement* of the Displays were. I immediately saw `-2560` as unique between the output and a way of determining the *current arrangement*.  If I `grep`ed for `-2560` and found it then I was in the *flipped arrangement*, not the *normal arrangement*. So this is what I used to determine the *current arrangement* and thus toggle between the two *arrangements*. (Note: `-2560` was not the only thing unique, it's just what I focused on first and felt an easy way to parse the information to set a *toggle flag* with.)

Save the AppleScript *code* below as an application and place a copy of the `hmscreens` binary executable file within the `<appname>.app/Contents/Resources` folder.  This way the app, e.g. `/Applications/Toggle Displays Arrangements.app` is self-contained and not dependent on an external location of the `hmscreens` binary executable file.

Obviously you'll need to determine what to `grep` for or use a different method to set the *toggle flag* and modify the *code* below accordingly to suite your particular needs (if other then this use case or a different use case).

AppleScript *code*:

```
set hms to (path to me as text) & "Contents:Resources:hmscreens"

set screenIDs to paragraphs of (do shell script quoted form of POSIX path of hms & " -screenIDs")
if (count of screenIDs) is greater than 1 then

    set normalOrentation to "1"
    try
        set normalOrentation to do shell script quoted form of POSIX path of hms & " -info | grep '\\-2560'"
    end try
    if normalOrentation is "1" then
        set othersPosition to "left"
    else
        set othersPosition to "right"
    end if

    set secondScreen to item 1 of screenIDs
    do shell script quoted form of POSIX path of hms & " -setMainID " & secondScreen & " -othersStartingPosition " & othersPosition

else

    tell me
        activate
        display dialog "Only one screen is attached to your computer!" buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with icon note
    end tell

end if
```

---

The image below shows syntactical highlighting of the AppleScript *code*.

[image: AppleScript Code]

Comment: I am currently unable to get this working.  OS X kills `hmsscreens` instantly, before it can do anything:  `[1]    9612 killed     hmscreens -info`.  Any ideas how to fix this situation?

Comment: @iconoclast, This was posted two years ago, did you test it then and did it work, or are you just doing it for the first time. Also, have you tried re-downloading the file and trying with a fresh copy? Have you rebooted between failure? This still works for me with macOS High Sierra 10.13.5. When I originally posted this, I was using OS X Mountain Lion.

Comment: I believe it did work originally, but at some point stopped.

Comment: It's still working. Just copy the tool to your Applications Folder. Then start it using e.g. `/Applications/hmscreens -info` from in your command line

Answer (score 6):

`displayplacer` is perfect and made the bulk of the process very easy. I used it in an Automator script to switch between two arrangement profiles, and then set up the ability to trigger those scripts from the menu bar. Here's a record of the process I went through.

[image]

- Follow instructions [here](https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer) to install displayplacer and get the commands to set your two layouts.
- Follow directions [here](https://dev.to/adamlombard/macos-run-a-script-in-any-app-via-custom-hotkey-4n99) to make an Automator script.
- In order for my script to run without errors, I had to add the line `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` before running the displayplayer command. Advice taken from [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97502/my-automator-workflow-fails-because-it-fails-to-find-the-git-command-within-the).
- To run scripts from the menu bar, check out [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/117895/308005).
- My "quick action" Automator scripts were being saved in `/Users/alfordsimon/Library/Services`, but the previous link expected them to be placed in `/Users/alfordsimon/Library/Scripts`, so I moved them over.

Comment: Thanks a lot for collating all the steps! Worked out perfectly for me.

Comment: Absolutely great solution!

Answer (score 4):

This isn't AppleScript, but here is a python library that that interfaces with PyObjC bindings that provides in-depth control of Mac display settings called "Display Manager". We have updated Display Manager, which is an open-source python library which can modify a individual or fleet of Mac's display settings manually or automatically. It programmatically manages Mac displays, including display resolution, refresh rate, rotation, brightness, screen mirroring, and HDMI underscan. Its primary intended purpose is to allow system administrators and developers to automatically configure any number of Mac displays, by use of the command-line scripts and the Display Manager Python library. It can easily be integrated in Jamf Pro, Outset or Munki or other client management systems.

We use Display Manager in our environment for multiple use cases like on our digital display systems to rotate the display 90 degree's and exactly set the HDMI underscan, on podiums setting video mirroring and allow the instructor quickly toggle mirroring on or off, set default resolution & brightness on shared systems like student labs or staff/faculty systems and reset the default after at times like user login/logout or on demand, etc.

If you are interested in reviewing the code or trying it out see the following GitHub repository...

https://github.com/univ-of-utah-marriott-library-apple/display_manager

Please let us know if you have an question, problems or have feature requests.

Comment: This looks interesting, but possibly overkill for what I want.  (But I'm not the down-voter, by the way.  In fact... I'm going to upvote, since it does seem _potentially_ useful.) Thanks for posting it!

Comment: Sure, np. Let use know if you have any questions, problems or feature requests.

Comment: Just forked this.  Looks like exactly what I was after!

Answer (score 4):

I used the examples above to create a simple apple script "Swap Screens".

```
display dialog "Swap Screens?" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button "OK" cancel button "Cancel" giving up after 15

set hms to "Applications:hmscreens"
set screenIDs to paragraphs of (do shell script quoted form of POSIX path of hms & " -screenIDs")
if (count of screenIDs) is greater than 1 then

    set firstScreen to item 1 of screenIDs

    set secondScreen to item 2 of screenIDs

    set othersPosition to "right"

    do shell script quoted form of POSIX path of hms & " -setMainID " & secondScreen & " -othersStartingPosition " & othersPosition

else

    display dialog "Only See One Screen"

end if
```

It worked like a champ ... I can click one icon and my screens align just like I want them to.

Enjoy!
E-

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [Hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org) to do this programmatically.  I have this in my Hammerspoon init script:

```
-- swap which is primary screen: external monitor or laptop
hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd", "alt", "ctrl", "shift"}, "f11", function()
  -- allScreens seems to return the screens in order of primary, non-primary
  -- so with two screens, this always operates on the non-primary 
  hs.screen.allScreens()[2]:setPrimary()
end)
```

Comment: Swapping position is not the same as swapping which is primary.  Does this also swap the physical position of the monitors?

Comment: In my experience it does not change the physical position of the monitors; it just changes which screen is primary.

(I'm using OSX 10.13.6 and Hammerspoon 0.9.78)