# Change display arrangement in OS X/macOS programmatically using USB-C/HDMI port number

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, usb, hdmi

Every time I turn my computer from sleep the display arrangement changes randomly.

I have tried all these solutions from this post but they don't work for me because the persistent/contextual IDs keep changing randomly also
[Change display arrangement in OS X/macOS programmatically](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/249447/change-display-arrangement-in-os-x-macos-programmatically)

I use three monitors that are the same model (Samsung M5) connected one by HDMI and the other two by USB-C (thunder bolt) port. Each one has a different port and I never switch the ports. MacOS should use the port number instead of persistent/contextual IDs because those keep switching.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can confirm this is a super annoying issue when using PBP on an ultra wide. Displays swap entirely randomly, and changing the inputs on the monitor itself (between DP1/2 on left/right) only fixes it half the time as OSX keeps randomising.

Comment: @RudiVisser This is not a solution but maybe helps you too. I realized that ONE GOOD monitor is enough and it's better because you can focus more. I have never been so productive.